# Is there a way to get Clojure file's source when a namespace provided?

Tags: clojure

There are some functions that read source code of a function like: `source` and `source-fn`.

Is there any way or function that returns source code of the Clojure file when a namespace is provided?

Such as: `(all-source 'my-ns)`

Returns such as:

```
(ns my-ns
  (:require [kezban.core :refer :all]
            [leiningen.c.util :as util]))
(defn my-fn
  []
  )
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a way(it works if the ns has at least one var):

```
(defn source-clj
  [ns]
  (require ns)
  (some->> ns
           ns-publics
           vals
           first
           meta
           :file
           (.getResourceAsStream (RT/baseLoader))
           IOUtils/toString))
```